# Import/Export JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

He intentado exportar una función que pide dos números al usuario, hace una serie de cálculos matemáticos e imprime todo ello en una etiqueta html `textarea`

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

math.html

```
<body>

    <script type="import" src="../js/main.js"></script>
    //LÍNEA AÑADIDA
    <div id="textarea"></div>
    <button onclick="mathTextArea();">pulsar aquí</button>

</body>
```

mathFunctions.js

```
   export function mathTextArea (){

    let input = prompt("INTRODUCIR NÚMERO A , B: ");
    let numbers = input.split(',');

    let a = numbers[0];
    let b = numbers[1];

    let result =  `

    Neperiano:            ${(Math.log(a))}  
    Raíz:                 ${(Math.sqrt(a))}
    Elevado:              ${(Math.pow(a,b))}
    Más cercano y menor:  ${(Math.floor(a))}
    Más cercano y mayor:  ${(Math.ceil(b))}
    Redondeo:             ${(Math.round(a))}
    Número random (0-1):  ${(Math.random())}  Número random (a-b): ${(Math.random(a * b))}
    Seno:                 ${(Math.sin(b))}
    Coseno:               ${(Math.cos(b))}
    Tangente:             ${(Math.tan(b))}
    Absoluto:             ${(Math.abs(a))}
    Valor máximo:         ${(Math.max(a,b))}
    Valor mínimo:         ${(Math.min(a,b))}
    Hipotenusa:           ${(Math.hypot(a,b))}

     `;

    document.write("<textarea>" + result + "</textarea>");

     }
```

y por último el archivo main.js donde decido importar todas las funciones que necesite, teniendo así todo el códido de una forma más organizada y solamente teniendo que añadir una etiqueta `script` en el código html

```
import {mathTextArea} from './mathFunctions';
//LÍNEA AÑADIDA
let zone = document.getElementById("textarea");
zone.addEventListener("click", mathTextArea);
```

Cuando se hace click en el botón ubicado en el math.html la consola de comandos del navegador web reporta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier documentación para arreglar este error, solución o consejo sobre una mejor estructura de los archivos y código.

Por último adjunto al estructura de directorios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Haz un par de cambios, pon type "module" en la importación:

```
<script type="module" src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

y añade ".js" al import de mathFunctions:

```
import { mathTextArea } from './mathFunctions.js';
```

Con eso te debería cargar correctamente el objeto mathTextArea.

---

EDIT: Añado los tres ficheros que tengo para reproducir la prueba:

./html/index.html

```
    <body>

        <script type="module" src="../js/main.js"></script>
        <button onclick="mathTextArea();">pulsar aquí</button>

    </body>
```

./js/main.js

```
    import { mathTextArea } from './mathFunctions.js';

    object.addEventListener("click", mathTextArea);
```

./js/mathFunctions.js

```
export function mathTextArea (){
    let input = prompt("INTRODUCIR NÚMERO A , B: ");
    let numbers = input.split(',');

    let a = numbers[0];
    let b = numbers[1];

    let result =  `

    Neperiano:            ${(Math.log(a))}  
    Raíz:                 ${(Math.sqrt(a))}
    Elevado:              ${(Math.pow(a,b))}
    Más cercano y menor:  ${(Math.floor(a))}
    Más cercano y mayor:  ${(Math.ceil(b))}
    Redondeo:             ${(Math.round(a))}
    Número random (0-1):  ${(Math.random())}  Número random (a-b): ${(Math.random(a * b))}
    Seno:                 ${(Math.sin(b))}
    Coseno:               ${(Math.cos(b))}
    Tangente:             ${(Math.tan(b))}
    Absoluto:             ${(Math.abs(a))}
    Valor máximo:         ${(Math.max(a,b))}
    Valor mínimo:         ${(Math.min(a,b))}
    Hipotenusa:           ${(Math.hypot(a,b))}

     `;

    document.write("<textarea>" + result + "</textarea>");
}
```

Comment: De todas formas tienes una referencia a `object` sin definir, entiendo que es código en progreso y que vas a hacer algo por ahí para arreglarlo.

Comment: Aún estoy haciendo el código. Haciendo las modificaicones que has comentado anteriormente y añadiendo las líneas de código que acabo de editar aún me sigue saltando el mismo error. He comentado dónde se han realizado los nuevos cambios. Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué curioso, a mi me funciona así en mi entorno, ¿lo tienes en caché? CTRL+F5 en el navegador. ¿Lo tienes desplegado en un servidor web o lo tienes en una carpeta suelta?

Comment: Ahora mismo no lo tengo en ningún servidor, es un ejercicio académico por lo tanto lo tengo todo englobado en una carpeta. He consultado documentación que me han proporcionado pero la verdad es que ya no sé dónde se puede encontrar el error. Si necesita cualquier información adicional intetaré dársela lo antes porisble. Muchas gtacias de nuevo

Comment: Voy a ampliar la respuesta con los ficheros que tengo para la prueba.

Comment: Añado error más descriptivo proporcionado por la consola del navegador Chrome.

Comment: Yo si lo abro desde una carpeta me da el error: "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.". Si lo despliego en un servidor web no me da ese problema.

Comment: ¿Sobre qué tipo de servidor local podría desplegarlo para evitar este problema?

Comment: Debería valer con cualquier servidor web (apache web server, nginx...) Yo lo he probado en un tomcat, pero debería dar igual.